# Git for Windows: Authentication failed for 'https://dev.azure.com/my-orgnanization

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-repos, credential-manager

I've removed all credentials from credential manager starting with  `git:*` and `SSO*`.

When I run `git fetch` in my locally cloned repo and I log in using my Microsoft account I get:

> git fetch
> fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://dev.azure.com/my-org/MyProj/_git/MyProj/'

However, I'm able to log in with the same account to the Azure DevOps web portal, see and edit my files.

Additional Info:

- I use the same account to log in to my PC, however it is different organization/directory
- I have the same problem when trying to connect Team Explorer in Visual Studio 2019
- The SSO login dialog, that is popped out when trying git fetch sometimes does not even ask for password. Other times it does. It probably recognized, that it's the same account as my windows account.

**EDIT:**
Following helped:

1. Uninstall GIT and remove GIT folder from Program Files
2. Install latest Git for Windows with recommended settings
3. In Azure DevOps portal, [edit personal access tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page) to full access and scope: all accessible organizations

Not sure what of the previous helped. If it is #3, it could be a bug in Azure DevOps Repos

Comment: Try reinstalling git from machine.

Comment: tried, no success

Comment: Have you tried (re-)installing the Git Credential Manager Core? https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core/releases/latest

Answer (score 0):

Use the `user name` rather than email id as User name and password as `PAT`

Please use the below images as a reference

[image]

[image]